# String handling in ANSI C (Memory Allocation)

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management

How is it that I can assign a char* variable a string, and do not have to allocate memory previously?

For example if I have a function return a char* (a file path for example) and I would call the function this way.

```
char* path;
path = get_path();
```

How could I expect the char* to behave if I do not know what the length of the path will be?, is it strictly necessary to allocate the path's size prior it's assignment to "Path" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
char* path;
path = get_path();
```

`get_path` returns a pointer to (or, equivalently, the address of) a string. (A pointer to a string is a pointer to its first character). The assignment simply copies that pointer value, storing it in `path`.

The `get_path` function itself must have allocated space to hold the string somehow.

There are several ways it could have done that. Some make it the caller's responsibility to deallocate the space when it's no longer needed.

Recommend reading: the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com), especially sections 4 (Pointers), 6 (Arrays and Pointers), 7 (Memory Allocation), and 8 (Characters and Strings).

Comment: Thank you very much!, I will be reading that document for sure. But, what happens when I do something like path = "/home/blah" , how is it that the string is assigned with no previous  memory allocation ?

Comment: @GuillermoGruschka: The string literal itself has memory allocated for it. There's an anonymous array of `char` that exists for the lifetime of the program's execution (static storage duration) containing the characters `"/home/blah"` plus a terminating null character `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `get_path()` function is returning a pointer to a memory buffer of its own.  The question now is, who allocated that memory, and who is responsible for freeing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
char *path;//path is just a pointer
```

if you alloc memory for the path string in get_path(), you are just make the pointer(char *path) point to that memory.

Answer (score -1):

In `get_path` you would have to return the pointer to a variable already allocated. Like this:

```
char *get_path()
{
    char *var = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    setdirectory(var);
    return var;
}
```

where `n` is the size of the directory.

But since you said you don't the size of the directory you could get its name, count the words, allocate another amount of memory (that time the exact amount) and free the other one. That will help you with memory usage.

Comment: First, `var` only holds a single character. Second, returning the address of a local (non-`static`) variable causes undefined behavior, since `var` ceases to exist as soon as you return from `get_path()`.

Comment: Better, thanks (and I cleaned up your spelling a bit). A couple of notes: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition, and casting the result of `malloc()` is unnecessary and can hide errors. Simpler: `char *var = malloc(n);`